# How to declare a string constant in c# that has special characters

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How can I define the following XML as a string constant in my c# program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
  <meta base="rtmp://dos.com/vevood" />
  </head>
  <body>

 </body>
 </smil>
```

Right now I save the above as a test file(file.txt)  then use the following to load it into an xdocument:

```
XDocument.Load(@"G:\file.txt");
```

I would like to save the xml as a string then do something like:
    XDocument.Load(string);

The problem is there are special characters in the xml.

What's the easiest way to achieve my objective?

Comment: You can use verbatim string, you just need to escape the `"`:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `XDocument.Parse(string)` to initialize it from string constant. Also use double quotes to escape `"` characters:

```
string str = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<smil xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language/"">
  <head>
    <meta base=""rtmp://dos.com/vevood"" />
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</smil>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [C# `string` escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><smil xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language\"><head><meta base=\"rtmp://dos.com/vevood\" /></head><body></body></smil>";
```

should work